# COUNTIFS using AND / OR

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to count the number of records where any one of several conditions could be met in column G but a specific condition must be met in column I.

For example, column G could be either "Toyota" or "Mazda" but column I must be "2008".

I've tried the following but I get the wrong total

```
{=COUNTIFS(I2:I3053,="2008")+COUNTIFS(G2:G3053,"=Mazda")+COUNTIFS(G2:G3053,"=Toyota")}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current formula counts the rows with `2008`, adds then to those with `Mazda` and adds them to those with `Toyota`, which mean there are overlaps and you are likely to get a higher number than the actual number.

You could use 2 `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(I2:I3053,"=2008",G2:G3053,"=Mazda")+COUNTIFS(I2:I3053,"=2008",G2:G3053,"=Toyota")
```

This counts those 2008 which are Mazda and adds them to those 2008 which are Toyota.

Or maybe `SUMPRODUCT` would be simpler?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((I2:I3053=2008)*(G2:G3053={"Mazda","Toyota"}))
```

That one could be a little more difficult to understand, but the equalities should be rather straightforward.

Comment: Jerry, thanks for the two options. The SUMPRODUBT worked like a charm. You've saveed me a lot more time (already spent about 2 hours) trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Jerry, I've accepted your answer which has been a real time saver. However, I now need to add to the formula in order to include an option from another column. The requirement now is for something like this: column G could be either "Toyota" or "Mazda" but column I must be "2008" and column N must be "Yes". Any ideas?

Comment: @PaulGoodwin Just add another `*()` group and put the equation there: `=SUMPRODUCT((I2:I3053=2008)*(G2:G3053={"Mazda","Toyota"})*(N2:N3053="Yes"))` (Type the formula from scratch because the don't work if you copy/paste from comments as the formula breaks over two lines).

Comment: Jerry, again, worked a treat. Had almost cracked it but had missed the bracket after the } and put it at the end instead. having looked at your formula this now makes sense. Thanks